# how to load a ms chart control from a current page to new page.(client side)

Tags: c#, mschart

```
var divToPrint = document.getElementById('<%= Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder2").FindControl("divReport").ClientID %>');
var newWin = window.open('', '_blank', features);
newWin.document.open();
newWin.document.write('<html><head></head><body onload= "window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>'); 
newWin.document.close();
newWin.focus();
```

**Divreport** contains an MS-Chart control (c# asp.net).

The above code should display the chart control in new page and open a print window when a new page loads.

My question is, the chart control is loading correctly, but sometimes it wont, why is this happening? The chart control by itself change as an image and it will get loaded on other page (since I am using html).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by creating new chart in other page instead of passing. Just i have send the required data through query string.
:-)